# Data Table Getting error when i add data rows[]

Tags: c#, datatable

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Date", typeof(String)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Time", typeof(String)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Function", typeof(String)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Log Level", typeof(String)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Message", typeof(String)));
```

When i query *DataTable* then get `DataRows[]`

```
DataRow[] result = dt.Select("Function ='" + strfunction + "'");
```

Now i want to add that result in *DataTable*

```
dt.Rows.Add(result);
```

But i am getting error

> *Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table.*

Comment: Error message is clear in my opinion. Looks like your `result` has more than `5` columns and that's why you get error since your `dt` has `5` column. Show your `dTSearchIn` also..

Comment: I am searching in same table and how i can get more columns than it

Comment: What is `dTSearchIn` and why is `t` capital?

Comment: That is a datatable in which i am searching

Comment: This select dTSearchIn.Select is giving you more columns then you wait for

Comment: I am searching in table having five columns, and giving result back to same table how Number of columns can be greater ?

Comment: You are searching in dTSearchIn and not in dt. Check the schema of dTSearchIn. It should contain more than 5 columns. Else please edit your question to give us the schema of dTSearchIn.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
foreach (DataRow row in result)
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: This will give Error : **This row already belongs to this table.** .Please make it `dt.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);`

Comment: Missing `row = dt.NewRow();` in foreach

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly adding the `DataRow` to the `DataTable`, how about creating a `foreach` loop and creating a separate `DataRow` from the `DataTable`, filling the data and adding it into the `DataTable`. For example:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Date", typeof(String)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Time", typeof(String)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Function", typeof(String)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Log Level", typeof(String)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Message", typeof(String)));

//Dummy data added
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr[0] = "aa";
dr[1] = "bb";
dr[2] = "cc";
dr[3] = "dd";
dr[4] = "ee";

dt.Rows.Add(dr);

string strfunction = "cc";
DataRow[] result = dt.Select("Function ='" + strfunction + "'");

//Initialize Datarow here. I am using the one which is defined above
dr = null;

foreach (var item in result)
{
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr[0] = item[0];
    dr[1] = item[1];
    dr[2] = item[2];
    dr[3] = item[3];
    dr[4] = item[4];

    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`DataRowCollection.Add()` has two *overloads*:

- `Add(DatarRow row);`
- `Add(params object[] values);`

The one you are currently using is `Add(params object[] values);` since you are passing an array of a class with base class of `object`. So you are searching in the same table, getting the **same number of columns** indeed, but the problem is that; you expect each element of the array to be *inserted* as a `DataRow`, but there is **only one row inserted** and each element of the array `DataRow[] result` is assigned for `columns`

With:

```
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Date", "Time", "a", "Log Level", "Message" });
DataRow[] result = dt.Select("Function ='a'");

foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
{
    /* Log r or inpect */
}
```

No exception was thrown in my test because the `result` array had only 1 element (as search result).

If i have more then 5 elements in `result`; since i can't insert 6 column values in a 5 column table it will throw exception.

And the correct way to do it is `interating` search results array and adding a new row for each array element; using `DataRow.ItemArray` property

You can try the following which worked for me:

```
DataRow[] result = dt.Select("Function ='" + strfunction + "'");

foreach (DataRow r in result)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(r.ItemArray);
}
```